# Recyclerview Ads

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob

I am new to Android.  I am making simple App in which I want to show banner ads on RecyclerView. After few items it should show banner ad. I have 1 recylerview, 1 adapter and retrieving data from the text file placed in asset folder. I have looked all tutorials on google but not understood need some help.

MainActivity

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_sad);

                RecyclerView quoteList = findViewById(R.id.quoteList);
                quoteList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                quoteList.setAdapter(new QuotesAdapter(getQuotes(),this));


            }

            private List<String> getQuotes() {
                List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

                try {
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("text1.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        quotes.add(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (bufferedReader != null) {
                        try {
                            bufferedReader.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return quotes;
            }
```

xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/li"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#9c27B0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/quoteList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

customlayout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/quoteContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:src="@drawable/quote"
            android:tint="#fff"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtQuote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a Sample quote. You can write anything you want."
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

If understood correctly you want to show ads in your recyclerview on certain intervals. If this is the case you have to make some changes in your adapter.

First define these variables in your adapter.

```
static final int VIEW_TYPE_NEWS = 0;
static final int VIEW_TYPE_AD = 1;
boolean isAd = false;
```

Next on your onCreateViewHolder method you have to do something like this. See there are two different list_item layouts, don't forget to create them in your layouts.

```
   @Override
    public ViewHolderNews onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        int layoutId = -1;

        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_AD:
                layoutId = R.layout.list_ad_item;
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_NEWS:
                layoutId = R.layout.list_news_item;
                break;
        }

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(layoutId, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolderNews(view);
}
```

Then onBindViewHolder:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderNews holder, int position) {

        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_AD:
                // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
                // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
                // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."

                // Load your ad here.

                break;

            case VIEW_TYPE_NEWS:

               // Load your normal content here.

                break;
        }
}
```

Finally last method to override is this:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int positionNew = position + 1;
        if ((positionNew % ITEMS_PER_AD == 0) && (position > 0)) {
            isAd = true;
            return VIEW_TYPE_AD;
        } else {
            isAd = false;
            return VIEW_TYPE_NEWS;
        }
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: ITEMS_PER_AD is another int variable you should define. That is for example: lets say ITEMS_PER_AD = 7; that means your ad is gonna be shown after 7 rows of content.